# How to add more than one iframe within of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

First, sorry for my english but I'm not native and It's my first post (Yep, I'm new member here).

I have the following HTML and jQuery code:

```
<div id="info" style="width: 100%; height:280px;">

if (sectores.getVisible()) {
  if (url1) { 
    $('#info').html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" seamless src="' + url1 + '"></iframe>');
  } 
}
if (despachos.getVisible()) {
  if (url1) { 
    $('#info').html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" seamless src="' + url2 + '"></iframe>');
  }
}
```

Result:
It works but only show me the last "iframe".
I've thought I need to put "the iframes" within a stack or something similar... But I'm not really sure.

So, I'd like to visualize more than one iframe within of info 'div'.

Comment: are both the `if` conditions are true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way would be to [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the iframes into the parent. Typically, when doing that, you empty the parent prior to any append operations:

```
var $info = $("#info");
$info.empty();

if (sectores.getVisible()) {
  if (url1) { 
    $info.append('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" seamless src="' + url1 + '"></iframe>');
  } 
}

if (despachos.getVisible()) {
  if (url1) { 
    $info.append('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" seamless src="' + url2 + '"></iframe>');
  }
}
```

If you want to perform fewer DOM modifications or have some special-case, you can build up multiple elements in a string before adding them to the DOM:

```
var $info = $("#info");
$info.empty();

var info_html = "";

if (sectores.getVisible()) {
  if (url1) { 
    info_html += '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" seamless src="' + url1 + '"></iframe>';
  } 
}

if (despachos.getVisible()) {
  if (url1) { 
    info_html += '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" seamless src="' + url2 + '"></iframe>';
  }
}

$info.html(info_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically overwriting one piece of code with another when you use `.html()`.

What you should do instead is:

```
$('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" seamless src="' + url1 + '"></iframe>').appendTo('#info');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the second iframe into a second "div"?
I would think that your second one is overriding the first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.html()` you should use `.append()` else the second `.html()` will write the first `.html()`

```
if (sectores.getVisible()) {
  if (url1) { 
    $('#info').append('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" seamless src="' + url1 + '"></iframe>');
  } 
}
if (despachos.getVisible()) {
  if (url1) { 
    $('#info').append('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" seamless src="' + url2 + '"></iframe>');
  }
}
```